# Writing Haskell's break in ReactiveCocoa

Tags: objective-c, haskell, sequence, reactive-programming, reactive-cocoa

I need to have a ReactiveCocoa function which is like Haskell's `break`:

```
break                   :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a],[a])
break _ xs@[]           =  (xs, xs)
break p xs@(x:xs')
           | p x        =  ([],xs)
           | otherwise  =  let (ys,zs) = break p xs' in (x:ys,zs)
```

Basically return a tuple whose first component is all the items that did *not* match and that come *before the first match*. The second component is the item that matches and the tail of the list (whether they match or not).

The direct translation to ReactiveCocoa is

```
- (RACTuple *)breakSequence:(RACSequence *)seq withBlock:(BOOL(^)(NSString *))matchBlock
{
    id head = [seq head];
    if (matchBlock(head)) {
        return [RACTuple tupleWithObjects:[RACSequence empty], seq, nil];
    } else {
        RACTuple *t = [self breakSequence:[seq tail] withBlock:matchBlock];
        return [RACTuple tupleWithObjects:[RACSequence sequenceWithHeadBlock:^id{
            return head;
        } tailBlock:^RACSequence *{
            return [t first];
        }], [t second], nil];
    }
}
```

Obviously it works but suffers from stack overflows because of the recursion of `breakSequence:seq withBlock:`.

What would be the best way to implement this function sanely in ReactiveCocoa?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My other version seems a bit ugly but works, posting below. Gonna use what @Justin Spahr-Summers suggested.

```
- (RACTuple *)betterBreakSequence:(RACSequence *)seq withBlock:(BOOL(^)(NSString *))matchBlock
{
    RACSequence *left = [seq takeUntilBlock:matchBlock];
    NSNumber *count = [left foldLeftWithStart:@0 reduce:^id(NSNumber *accumulator, id value) {
        return [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[accumulator integerValue]+1];
    }];
    RACSequence *right = [seq skip:[count integerValue]];
    return [RACTuple tupleWithObjects:left, right, nil];
}
```

Comment: Ah, indeed. Sorry, I got distracted by "[returns] a tuple whose first component is all the items that did not match the predicate." This is a totally valid implementation, but you may prefer traversing `seq.tail` to remove the need for a `-skip:` afterward, and so you don't need to evaluate the full sequence.

Comment: Sorry, clarified my question, was indeed misleading. And thanks for your comments.

Comment: @JustinSpahr-Summers Me again, sorry. I think I can't totally follow what you mean by "... you may prefer traversing `seq.tail` to remove the need for a `-skip:` afterward". I'd love to get rid of the `-skip`, could you elaborate a bit? Many Thanks

Comment: You can iteratively traverse a sequence by initializing `RACSequence *x = seq;` and then repeatedly set `x = x.tail;` to step node-by-node (like you would with a normal linked list). Once you've found the node to break around, you can just return `x` as the second tuple value, since you've already done the equivalent of `skip:`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, totally makes sense now. I just wasn't thinking in loops and looked for some functional way to write it but in ObjC the for loop makes sense. Thank you!